# sylow subgroup of a subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and $H$ a subgroup of a finite group $G$. Let $P$  be a p-sylow subgroup of G. Prove that there exists $g\in G$ such that $H\cap gPg^{-1}$ is  sylow subgroup of $H$.

I have no idea how to do this, any hints?

*Note:* Originally it was unclear if the problem was for possibly infinite groups or just finite ones. However, since the definition of $p$-Sylow subgroup being used is that it is a $p$-subgroup such that the index and the order are relatively prime, the definition only applies to finite groups.

Comment: $G$ need not be finite.

Comment: edit the question and add the information that $G$ need not be finite *there*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note:** The following works if $G$ is finite, but may fail in the infinite case; there are infinite groups in which there are $p$-Sylow subgroups $P$ and $P'$ for which no automorphism (inner or outer) of $G$ maps $P$ to $P'$.

Let $K$ be a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$ (we know it exists, though it may be trivial). Then $K$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$ (even if $K={e}$) and by the Sylow Theorems, is contained in *some* Sylow $p$-subgroup $Q$ of $G$. By the Sylow Theorems, $Q$ and $P$ are conjugate. Now just verify that $Q\cap H = K$.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I've only one question, and I'm sorry for all the trouble: Do all p-Sylow subgroups are conjugate even if G is infinite? (if it isn't to much trouble could you mention a book that proves this?) Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: This apparently is not true in general.  See http://www.mscand.dk/article.php?id=1527 for a counterexample.

Comment: You're right, so the solution above doesn't work :(. Could it be possible the result is only valid for $G$ finite?

Comment: @Chu: Apparently not, as Hans notes. Please un-accept and I'll see if there is a way around it in the infinite case.

Comment: @Chu: Are you positive the problem asks you to consider possibly infinite groups?

Comment: This was on an exam I took recently and I couldn't solve this one. It's phrased without any assumptions on $G$'s finiteness so I assumed it could be infinite.

Comment: @Chu: Let me ask you this: How did you define "$p$-Sylow subgroup"? Was it defined as a maximal $p$-subgroup, or was it defined as a $p$-subgroup $P$ such that the order and the index of the subgroup were relatively prime, or as a subgroup whose order is the maximum power of $p$ that divides the order of $G$? The *definition*, not any equivalences proven later.

Comment: We defined it as a p-subgroup P such that the order and the index are coprime.  So now I see this was intended for the finite case right? I'm sorry for all the trouble. I'll edit the question and re-accept your answer. Thanks again :).

Comment: @Chu: Yes, if you defined it as a subgroup in which the order and index are coprime, then your definition, *a fortiori* assumes that the group $G$ is finite (otherwise, the definition does not make sense since at least one of the order and index will necessarily be infinite). One can instead define Sylow subgroups as "maximal $p$-subgroups", but then they don't always exist (in the infinite case), and as B.H. Neumann's paper shows, we can have weird things happening in the infinite case.

Answer (score 8):

Let $G$ be the direct product of countably many copies of the dihedral group $D$ of order 6 (or, if you prefer, $D$ is the symmetric group $S_3$).

We can construct a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ by choosing Sylow $2$-subgroups of each of the direct factors of $G$, and taking their direct product. Since $D$ has three Sylow $2$-subgroups, $G$ has uncountably many Sylow $2$-subgroups, so they cannot all be conjugate in the countable group $G$.

If we let $P$ and $H$ be non-conjugate Sylow $2$-subgroups of $G$, then there is no $g \in G$ such that $H \cap gPg^{-1} \in {\rm Syl}_2(H)$.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the example.

Comment: +1 - I like this better than the counterexample I found.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have $\vert P \vert =p^n$ where $\vert G \vert = p^n m$ and $(p,m)=1$.  What can be said about $\vert H \cap P \vert$ (or, for that matter, $\vert H \cap Q \vert$ for any Sylow p-subgroup $Q$ of $G$)?

Comment: Jack, you meant that $(p,m)=1$ right?

Comment: Indeed I did.  Thanks for catching that!  It's been fixed.

Comment: thanks for your time :), one of the problems I have with this is that $G$ isn't necesarily finite.

Comment: Ah, in that case, we know that for all $x\in P$, $\vert x \vert=p^n$ for some $n\geq 0$.  What does that tell us about elements of $H\cap P$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $P'$ be any Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$. Then there is a maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$ containing it. What is it?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Could it be possible that $H$ has no p-subgroups?

Comment: @Chu:  The trivial subgroup is a p-subgroup.